# Opening a PDF with search parameters just opens the PDF

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, pdf

I was requested to add some searching functionality to an existing system for the collection of PDFs that we have. I know about searching PDFs and opening them with search parameters and in a test application I wrote, it works like a dream. When trying to convert it over to our existing application the PDF opens but without the search terms or the advanced find of Acrobat Reader popping up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a snippet of the cs code :

```
case "PDF":
      string searchTerms = SearchWordsTB.Text;
      searchTerms = searchTerms.Replace(',', ' ');
      launchStr = "OpenPDF('" + e.Row.Cells[9].Text.Replace("\\", "/") + "','" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(e.Row.Cells[2].Text) + "','" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "','" + searchTerms + "')";
      break;
```

We are creating the list of documents on the fly and PDF is one of the options. Assuming I am understanding this correctly, A DataGrid is created with all these clickable rows that will execute a Javascript function when clicked. The Javascript function OpenPDF is shown below:

```
function OpenPDF(url, filename, ID, searchTerms) {
    if (searchTerms.length > 0) {
        window.open('FileViewer.aspx?name=' + filename + '&ID=' + ID + '&url=' + url + '#search="' + searchTerms + '"', 'mywindow' + windowCnt, 'width=800,height=600,location=no,resizable=yes');
    }
    else {
        window.open('FileViewer.aspx?name=' + filename + '&ID=' + ID + '&url=' + url, 'mywindow' + windowCnt, 'width=800,height=600,location=no,resizable=yes');
    }
    windowCnt++;
}
```

From following the debugging in the CS code, I know that I am properly stripping out the commas in the search terms so that shouldn't be the problem. What currently happens is the PDF file will open up just fine, but the search terms are not being used. I have tried following the debugger through the Javascript (which for me has always been spotty at best) but the breakpoint is never hit. It should also probably be noted that the Javascript function is kept in a separate Javascript File and is not inline in the aspx page. And yes, we are correctly referencing the Javascript file. I will be more than happy to update this post with any extra info that is requested. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve the desired results by using the http encode on the launch string as shown below.

```
launchStr = "OpenFile('" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(e.Row.Cells[9].Text.Replace("\\", "/") + "#search=\"" + searchTerms + "\"") + "','" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(e.Row.Cells[2].Text) + "','" + e.Row.Cells[0].Text + "','" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "')";
```

I then used the function to just open the window with the PDF in it. The problem I had was that without the HTTP Encode, the URL was just cutting off the search parameters. I believe this is because the #search="blah" isn't normally recognized as part of a URL and was therefore truncated. If anyone has a better reason, I would love to hear it.